# Can't get Python 3 to transfer POST data to PHP

Tags: php, python, http, post, urllib

I want to send a simple string from Python 3 to a PHP site that converts it into a .txt file. My entire code looks like this:

Python:

```
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request

str1 = "abcdefg"

url = "http://site.net/post.php"

aa = str1.encode('utf-8')
req = urllib.request.Request(url, aa)
req.add_header('Content-Type', 'this/that')
urllib.request.urlopen(req, data=aa)
```

PHP:

```
<?php

$handle = fopen("/dir/".name.".txt", "w");

$myContent = $_POST[aa];

fwrite($handle, $myContent);

fclose($handle);

?>
```

Python accesses the site, and a .txt file gets created, except the file is blank. I've tried changing `$_POST` to `$_GET` and `$_REQUEST`, as well as placing single and double quotes around `'aa'` in various places. I suspect that `Python` and `PHP` aren't communicating about the name of the string/data that I want it to interpret.

> EDIT: This PHP code already handles POST data from another website. The issue only arises with Python compatibility

Comment: I should mention that this PHP code already handles POST data from another website. The issue only arise with Python compatibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data you're sending is invalid. Following [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen):

> *data* should be a buffer in the standard application/x-www-form-urlencoded format. The urllib.parse.urlencode() function takes a mapping or sequence of 2-tuples and returns a string in this format. **It should be encoded to bytes before being used as the data parameter**.

The documentation also contains a [simple example](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/urllib.request.html#urllib-examples) you just need to follow:

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse

data = urllib.parse.urlencode({'spam': 1, 'eggs': 2, 'bacon': 0})
data = data.encode('utf-8')
request = urllib.request.Request("http://requestb.in/xrbl82xr")

# adding charset parameter to the Content-Type header.
request.add_header("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8")

f = urllib.request.urlopen(request, data)
print(f.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: I wasn't aware that my data needed to be in {:} form. I also thought it was redundant to data.encode and .urlencode, but doing the latter on the dict object works when I data.encode afterward. Doing only data.encode didn't register because it was just a str object, but there was no error since the data was utf8 formatted. Also, I neglected the header because I didn't think it would be necessary. How much could I alter it if I wanted?

Answer (score 2):

your data needs to be a hash like:

```
a = {}
a["name"] = "ben";
```

then you need to call urllib.urlencode on it

```
a = urllib.urlencode(a)
```

then call urlopen like this:

```
urllib.request.urlopen(req, a)
```

Comment: Still getting a TypeError message. urlencode doesn't seem to convert the data into utf8 bytes. So far, my above code:
    aa = str1.encode('utf-8')
is the only code that has converted it to an appropriate format, except the PHP seems to ignore it (but with no errors).

Comment: @tqastro: no, it's not an appropriate format, as the byte sequence you get doesn't contain a '=', so it can't be a valid POST data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use use `file_put_contents` and also `$_POST[aa]` is not valid it should  be `$_POST['aa']`

```
$file = "/dir/".name.".txt" ;
file_put_contents($file, $_POST['aa']);
```

And i think you should look at [httplib2](http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/)

```
from httplib2 import Http
from urllib import urlencode
h = Http()
str1 = body = {'aa': 'abcdefg'}
resp, content = h.request("http://site.net/post.php", "POST", urlencode(data))
```

Comment: Writing "POST" makes it think that I'm sending that as my data, and it errors. Also, are you saying to use urllib.**parse**.urlencode? That doesn't seem to encode correctly, as I am receiving a TypeError about needing bytes instead of strings.

Comment: See updated code forgot to tell you i was using `httplib2` see some detail examples http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/wiki/Examples